# Is using npm-ci by developers a good NPM working process?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I work at a largish project with ~10 devs. We have `package.json` and the resulting `package-lock.json` committed, and our ci pipeline does `npm ci` to restore packages according to `package-lock.json`.

Currently, the developers are instructed to clone the repo and run `npm install`. However, I found that `npm install` will install different versions that match the version spec in `package.json` - for example, `^5.0.5` might cause `npm install` to install version `5.1.1`, or to keep `5.0.5` if it was already in there.

So, I want to change the instructions for developers to:

- (common case) If you don't want to change packages or package versions, only use `npm ci`
- If you do, use `npm install` and/or `npm update` (possibly with `--save-dev`), test locally, and then commit the resulting `package.json` and `pacakge-lock.json`.

Are these instructions sound? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per documentation "this command is similar to `npm install`, except it's meant to be used in automated environments such as test platforms, continuous integration, and deployment -- or **any situation where you want to make sure you're doing a clean install of your dependencies**." (emphasis mine).

I prefer using it instead of "install", because it gives some insurances about state of node_modules folder.

- It will remove modules folder, if it is present, which will remove everything that is not in lock file, but may accidentally be present from previous install.
- It will throw an error if someone changed dependencies by hand and didn't updated lock file.
- It will be faster than install, because it doesn't need to build new dependency tree, and it will preserve versions of dependencies which were installed by tag (like `latest` or `next`) or by wild card (`*`). And sometimes this is a very good thing - recent [colors incident](https://fossa.com/blog/npm-packages-colors-faker-corrupted/) is a good illustration.

Basically it means that me and all my colleagues will get identical node_modules folder contents. One of the advantages of Yarn in early days were reproducible installs with lock-file, and it is considered a good practice.

Comment: Thanks. Honestly, I don't understand the point of `npm install` without a specific package/version - it's like an non-trustable `npm ci`. Maybe it's just the for historical reasons?

Comment: Before npm@6 there were no such command, so it is mostly by inertia. Also, command name doesn't make it easier to understand that it have advantages for developers in their day to day work. In all my projects where I use npm I specifically mention `npm ci` as a main command to install dependencies with brief description and link to npm docs

Comment: random thought. They should get rid of `npm install` (deprecated warning) and replace with things like `npm add-dep` and `npm remove-dep` and `npm sync-deps`.

Comment: `npm install` could be very useful when you want to refresh lock-file. For example, I have very large workspaces project. If I run `npm install` it would not only update some dependencies, but also reorganize and clean up lock-file, so it would be few thousands lines smaller. This is mainly because of deduplication for some dependencies and updated npm resolutions since version 8 (now 10). But don't want it on every install, but I want to run it from time to time to keep things fresh.